# df.rename() - TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm loading data and  after that, i'm trying to rename df columns to lower case:

```
journalist_data = pd.read_csv( cur_dir + 'fandango_score_comparison.csv')
journalist_data_clean = journalist_data.loc[:,['FILM','Fandango_Stars','Fandango_Ratingvalue','Fandango_votes','Fandango_Difference']]
journalist_data_clean_columns = journalist_data_clean.columns.str.lower()
journalist_data_clean.rename(index = str, columns =  journalist_data_clean_columns,inplace= True)
```

But i have this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ML/DataQuest/Statistics/Fandango project/Investigating Fandango Movie Ratings.py", line 40, in <module>
    journalist_data_clean.rename(index = str, columns =  journalist_data_clean_columns,inplace= True)
  TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable
```

The description of df:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 146 entries, 0 to 145
Data columns (total 5 columns):
FILM                    146 non-null object
Fandango_Stars          146 non-null float64
Fandango_Ratingvalue    146 non-null float64
Fandango_votes          146 non-null int64
Fandango_Difference     146 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(1), object(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just quoting an example about `"Lower Case Column Names In Pandas Dataframe"`, hope that will make some headway for you...

### Example dataFrame:

```
>>> df
             NAME  REPORTS  YEAR   <-- all column names are in upper-case
Cochice     Jason        4  2012
Pima        Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa     Jake        2  2014
Yuma          Amy        3  2014
```

### Map the lowering function to all column names

```
>>> df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)
>>> df
             name  reports  year
Cochice     Jason        4  2012
Pima        Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa     Jake        2  2014
Yuma          Amy        3  2014
```

### OR

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()
```